# How to label under a series of circles?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to label a series of circles. The label should be under the drawing and centered. Since I am new to Tikz I drew the series of circles like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\definecolor{rot}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{gruen}{RGB}{0,147,0}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\begin{document}
\huge
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gruen] (0,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (1,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (2,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (3,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (4,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (5,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (6,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (7,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (8,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (9,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (10,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (11,0) circle (0.15cm);
\node {Node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I found the node option but I am not be able to place it where I want to.

Comment: It depends, if you want to place the node centred or if you wan to place the node some place near the center? `\node at (5,-1) {Node};`

Comment: @Machzx please have look at the answer below if it meets the requirement

Comment: Any news? You got two answer, did any of them solve your problem. If it is, it would be good to accept it. So far as I see you not accept any of received answers on your questions ...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not entirely clear. Where you like to have label(s)? Below each circle, as this:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gruen}{RGB}{0,147,0}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 10mm,
  start chain = going right,
     C/.style = {circle, fill=gruen, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3mm},
every label/.append style = {font=\footnotesize, align=center}
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,12}
    \node [C, on chain, label=below:label\\ \i] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or one label at below sequence of circles:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{gruen}{RGB}{0,147,0}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 10mm,
  start chain = going right,
     C/.style = {circle, fill=gruen, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3mm},
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,12}
    \node (n\i) [C, on chain] {};
    \path (n1) -- node[font=\huge, below=3mm] {Sequenca name?} (n12);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i think you copied the same code for both compilations -- `Sequenca name?`

Comment: @jsbibra, you are right. Corrected now.

Comment: You could use `(chain-begin)` and `(chain-end)` instead of `(n1)` and `(n12)` and make the label independent on a number of nodes, as in `\path (chain-begin) -- node[font=\huge, below=3mm] {Sequenca name?} (chain-end);`

Comment: @Celdor, yes, you are right, I could have written it that way too, but I didn’t see much of an advantage. However, you can write an answer with your suggestion :-).

Comment: I supposed I could and thought about it but your example is (1) working and (2) the suggestion are only related to small bits of code. Although no huge advantage, I wanted OP to know those predefined names exists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\definecolor{rot}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{gruen}{RGB}{0,147,0}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[gruen] (0,0) circle (0.15cm) node[label=below:w](){};
\fill[gruen] (1,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (2,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (3,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (4,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (5,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (6,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (7,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (8,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (9,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (10,0) circle (0.15cm);
\fill[gruen] (11,0) circle (0.15cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**alternatively**
the code

```
\node[circle,fill=gruen,label=below:010101] (CircleNode) at (0,0)  {};
```

can be used to create the series of circles

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\definecolor{rot}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\definecolor{gruen}{RGB}{0,147,0}
\definecolor{blau}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%\fill[gruen] (0,0) circle (0.15cm) [label=below:w];
%\fill[gruen] (1,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (2,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (3,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (4,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (5,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (6,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (7,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (8,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (9,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (10,0) circle (0.15cm);
%\fill[gruen] (11,0) circle (0.15cm);
\node[circle,fill=gruen,label=below:010101] (CircleNode) at (0,0)  {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```